# Symfony2: how to get all entities of one type which are marked with "EDIT" ACL permission?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, acl, entitymanager

Can someone tell me how to get all entities of one type which are marked with "EDIT" ACL permission?

I would like to build a query with the Doctrine EntityManager.

Comment: It is related to [this question about filtering a list of domain objects based on the access control entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621220/symfony2-how-do-one-use-acl-to-filter-a-list-of-domain-objects-according-to-a-ce)

Comment: Can't be answered without details about your ACL. Is your control list in your database?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a default way of doing this. What you could do is to write your own service that adds a `Filter` to your `Doctrine` DQL queries.

For more info, see:

- https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/filters.html
- https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html

Hope this helps!