# How to avoid multiple DB queries with ACL hasPermission in a loop

Tags: optimization, symfony, doctrine-orm, acl

i'm using Symfony2, Doctrine and ACL and I run into performance issue.

In a Twig template I need to check current user's role for each of Company in a collection to display a link :

```
{%- if is_expr_granted("hasRole('ROLE_SUPPORT') or hasPermission(object, 'OPERATOR')", company) -%}
    <a href="configure">{{- company.name -}}</a>
{%- else -%}
```

I can see in the webProfiler that the 2 following queries are generated for each company :

```
SELECT a.ancestor_id
FROM acl_object_identities o 
INNER JOIN acl_classes c ON c.id = o.class_id INNER JOIN acl_object_identity_ancestors a ON a.object_identity_id = o.id
WHERE ((o.object_identifier = '154' AND c.class_type = 'St\\CoreBundle\\Entity\\Company'))`
```

And

```
SELECT o.id as acl_id, o.object_identifier, o.parent_object_identity_id, o.entries_inheriting, c.class_type, e.id as ace_id, e.object_identity_id, e.field_name, e.ace_order, e.mask, e.granting, e.granting_strategy, e.audit_success, e.audit_failure, s.username, s.identifier as security_identifier 
FROM acl_object_identities o
INNER JOIN acl_classes c ON c.id = o.class_id
LEFT JOIN acl_entries e
    ON ( e.class_id = o.class_id AND (e.object_identity_id = o.id OR e.object_identity_id IS NULL) ) 
LEFT JOIN acl_security_identities s ON ( s.id = e.security_identity_id )
WHERE (o.id =2189)
```

How to avoid querying in a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Acl identities can be preloaded within one query. See this question: [How do one use ACL to filter a list of domain-objects according to a certain user's permissions (e.g. EDIT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621220/how-do-one-use-acl-to-filter-a-list-of-domain-objects-according-to-a-certain-use)

You would have to add something like this to you controller

```
// you entities
$companies = ...

// the acl provider
$aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');

// build up array of object identities
$oids = array();
foreach ($companies as $company) {
  $oids[] = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($company);
}

// preload acls
$aclProvider->findAcls($oids); // preload Acls from database
```

Comment: Thanks room, we are going to test that:)