# Making a list of Doctrine entities accessible to a specific user based on a custom Voter in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

**Situation:** My application deals with Doctrine entities to which a User may or may not have access. Whether or not a specific User has access to a specific entity for a specific purpose is decided by a custom Voter object (the process of deciding whether or not a user has access is fairly complicated).

**Problem:** I need to show the User a list of Doctrine entities to which he has access. Possibly this list needs to be paginated. Because of the complexity of deciding whether or not a User has access to an Entity, creating a single DQL/SQL query for this is next to impossible (or at least extremely tricky).

**Question:** Is there a better way to build this list than just fetching all of the Entities from the database, looping over them, and asking the security.context whether or not the Entity has access (adding each Entity to which access is granted to an array until I have built an array with enough Entities in it to fill the page)? Can I somehow take the Voter into account when asking doctrine for a list of entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what ACL's are meant for.

Please read the book chapter [How to use Access Control Lists (ACLs)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html).

Further information can be found in [this blog post](http://blog.mayflower.de/1944-ACLs-and-Symfony2.html) and the links at the bottom of the article.

Now that you've setup ACL's you can use possible solutions from [this blog](http://sf.khepin.com/2012/03/doctrine-objects-schizophrenia-the-acl/) post,  [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201279/symfony2-how-to-get-all-entities-of-one-type-which-are-marked-with-edit-acl-p) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621220/how-do-one-use-acl-to-filter-a-list-of-domain-objects-according-to-a-certain-use).

You could aswell have a look at the ACLHelper in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mailaneel/1363377).

Comment: Ok, I had hoped to avoid the extra hassle of maintaining ACL's but if that's the only way, so be it :) Thanks